# Linear dependence on the Grassmannian

Tags: linear-algebra, grassmannians

If I have $k+1$ linearly dependent points on the Grassmannian $G_{k-1,n-1}$ (I am using projective dimension), what can I say on the corresponding $(k-1)$-subspaces of the projective space $\mathbb{P}^ {n-1}$?

E.g.: three collinear points of $G_{1,n-1}$ are the plucker embedding of three concurrent lines of $\mathbb{P}^ {n-1}$ contained in a plane.

What can I say in general?

Comment: By "linearly dependent" you mean "linearly dependent after you embed the Grassmannian into a projective space via the Plücker embedding"?

Comment: yes! thank you for pointing that out.